# Jquery - Getting data from database when dialog window opens

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a form and on that form there is a table of records. Each record is from a mysql database and each record has its own unique id in the database. I'm using the Jquery UI dialog library, next to each record there is an edit link. When a person clicks edit the dialog is called to open, which shows a modal window of the form to edit that specific record. My question is, how would I make a call via jquery/ajax when the dialog box opens so I can grab the latest data from the database for that record and then populate the fields inside the dialog form? Right now I just open the dialog when a link is clicked:

```
$("a.editlink").click(function() {

    $("#edit-form").dialog("open");

    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to put the ajax call in the OPEN section of your dialog js code:

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Create an account": function() {

                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
                    open: function(){ 
         PUT AJAX CALL HERE
        }
    });
```

And put innerHTML into the ajax success to put the results into the dialog form:

```
function ajaxSuccess(data){
                     dialogformfields.innerHTML=data.info;
                     }
```

Hope that's what you needed to know!

Comment: I like this method, however one thing I'm stumped on is how would I pass the id from the link I am clicking to the open function so I can pass it along to my ajax call? So lets say on the parent page I have a link like so <a href="#" title="2" class="editthis">Edit</a> When they click that I call the dialog open, how do I access the title attribute from the link I just clicked from the open function?

Comment: OK, change your initial function to:
    $("a.editlink").click(function(this) {
    DO AJAX CALL HERE with this.title
    $("#edit-form").dialog("open");
    ...

Answer (score 0):

Inside the click function you would need to do an Ajax call to retrieve the information using http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

In the success method of the ajax call you could then assign the returned values to the input fields on your form.

I don't know what technology your back end is, so you would just need to make sure that is returning the values in a readable way (ie. JSON).

The only thing to consider is that this will be slow for the user when they click edit.  If the page doesn't have too much data, it might be worth storing the additional attributes in the anchor tag that is clicked so you can then populate the edit form instantly.

ie. have an anchor tag that looks like this:

```
<a class="editlink" data-field1='stuff' data-field2='stuff' data-field3='stuff'>Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your a tag has an href value set to a page where the editform is available. You pass the id of the record using querystring to this page so that you can load the details of that record to the edit form.

```
<a href="edtiuser.php?userid=1">Edit User 1</a>
<a href="edtiuser.php?userid=2">Edit User 2</a>
```

and have this script.

```
$(function(){
        $("a.editlink").click(function (e) {
            var url = this.href;
            var dialog = $("#dialog");
            if ($("#dialog").length == 0) {
                dialog = $('<div id="dialog" style="display:hidden"></div>').appendTo('body');
            }
            dialog.load(
                url,
                {}, // omit this param object to issue a GET request instead a POST request, otherwise you may provide post parameters within the object
                function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    dialog.dialog({                       
                        close: function (event, ui) {                            
                            dialog.remove();
                        },
                        modal: true,
                        width: 460
                    });
                }
            );           
            return false;           
        });
  });
```

So when you click on the anchror tag, the content of your edituser.php page will be loaded to the dialog. This should work fine, assuming you have jQuery and jQuery UI loaded properly to your page.